# Actionbar Icon on SDK21

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Maybe this is a very basic question, but I searched a lot and didn´t found an explanation of why this isn´t working...

What I´m trying to do is display my application icon at left on action bar, without using a custom view and without enabling it as Up Button...

I tried setIcon, setLogo, none of them worked...
I remember that showing the icon was the default behavior some time ago...

Here is my build.gradle and my MainActivity.

Thanks!

**Build.Gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.example.myapplication2.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package br.com.example.myapplication2.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Toolbar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> - *A title and subtitle.* The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content contained there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended information about the current content. **If an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.**
>
> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

However, if you want an application icon, [setLogo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) is indeed the correct method.

Comment: Hello @ianhanniballake. I tried to use actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher) but it´s still not showing the icon... Any other advice? 

Just to clarify: I´m talking about the icon that appears on the LEFT Side of action bar, ok? The one marked with the #1 on this image: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png

Answer (score 1):

Was looking at this today, before reading ianhanniballake's post. Took me a couple of hours to track down why some of my app were displaying this icon, but others weren't.

The answer: replace `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2` (or whatever newer support appcompat you are usingt) with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0`.

To do so in Android Studio:
Press f4
Go to Dependencies

Remove 21.0.2 or whatever you are using now.

Click add - select 21.0.2 and just rename the text 7:20.0.0 (or just type in the full package name).

As ianhanniballake mentioned. The icon is no longer recommended. However it is odd that the standard packages still use it while the appcompats seems to default it off...

Comment: Do you know how to do that in eclipse?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
} - I would imagine you change the line here to include 7:20.0.0 instead. Make sure you have the correct support library installed. As pointed out earlier, make sure to check the latest recommendations from Google. If you install the demos in the SDK, there are some good examples.